# cannot install neither electric nor unstable

Tags: opencv2, ubuntu, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello list

I use ubuntu 10.04(lucid) 64 bit.
I have been using diamondback for a while with no problems
Due to some new code I need, which does not exist on diamondback, I tried to upgrade to unstable, so I removed all the diamondback stacks using synaptic and installed unstable
one day after, ubuntu reported a partial upgrade regarding the ros unstable stacks.
After that partial upgrade, some packages have been removed and could not be installed. I get the error msg: "error dependancy ros-unstable-opencv, but it cannot be installed"
Among these packages are:
ros-unstable-opencv
ros-unstable-image-pipeline
ros-unstable-simulator
Same problem happens with ros-electric
I had to revert back to diamondback
Anyone else having problems installing either electric or unstable short ago?

Best regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10929/cannot-install-neither-electric-nor-unstable/) by [Moataz Elmasry](https://answers.ros.org/users/116/moataz-elmasry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2011-08-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moataz Elmasry](https://answers.ros.org/users/116/moataz-elmasry/) on 2011-08-16**:
I investigated further into the problem. Tits a dependancy problem and is caused by unmatched version of opencv. This is the error message I get when installing ros-unstable-vision-opencv: ros-unstable-vision-opencv: Depends: libopencv2.3-dev (=2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-1~lucid) but 2.3.0+svn5720+trunk-5~lucid is to be installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This should be resolved now if you run 'apt-get update'

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moataz Elmasry](https://answers.ros.org/users/116/moataz-elmasry/) on 2011-08-17**:
nop.I was using the freiburg repo, now I switched to the main ros repo, and I can install ros unstable like charm. Many thanks for the quick reaction

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-08-17**:
so, do you still get the opencv error?

**Comment by [Moataz Elmasry](https://answers.ros.org/users/116/moataz-elmasry/) on 2011-08-17**:
sorry about the 'USA' server, for a minute I thought ros packages are being pulled from the ubuntu server, my mistake

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-08-17**:
Did you run "sudo apt-get update" after you changed the repository?  I was able to update on my machine.  Also, not sure what you mean by 'USA' server as we only run 1 server.  You need packages.ros.org/ros as your repository.

**Comment by [Moataz Elmasry](https://answers.ros.org/users/116/moataz-elmasry/) on 2011-08-17**:
Thnx for the reply. I tried to make an update, no new packages appear, I live in germany, so I changed the repository server to USA server (not that it should matter), and still got no updates